# How to create composite primary key on multiple accessor properties in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework-6, key, primary-key, composite

I'm trying to create a composite key based on three navigation properties in Entity Framework 6 : ManufacturingBundle_Id, Part_Id and Process_Id

Here is my PartProcess class I use at the moment with Id being the Primary key:

```
public class PartProcess
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ManufacturingBundle ManufacturingBundle { get; set; }
    public virtual Part Part { get; set; }
    public virtual Process Process { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment I get the automatically generated database table that has the following Columns:
Id | ManufacturingBundle_Id | Part_Id | Process_Id

where Id is the Primary key. I would like to get rid of the Id Column and make a composite Primary key based on ManufacturingBundle_Id, Part_Id and Process_Id

So I tried overloading the OnModelCreating method but this doesn't seem to work on typed objects, the debuggers says the properties need to be ints.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      // create a composite primary key for PartProcess https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/haskey-method
      modelBuilder.Entity<PartProcess>()
                .HasKey(o => new { o.ManufacturingBundle, o.Part, o.Process });

      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

How must I declare this composite primary key because I use navigation properties and the  ManufacturingBundle_Id, Part_Id and Process_Id properties are autogenerated by Entity Framework?

Thanks for your help,

Ephie

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ManufacturingBundle has a ManufacturingBundleId field for instance, you'd need to configure your model as follows:

```
public class PartProcess
{
    public int ManufacturingBundleId { get; set; }
    public virtual ManufacturingBundle ManufacturingBundle { get; set; }

    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public virtual Part Part { get; set; }

    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public virtual Process Process { get; set; }
}
```

Then it should let you create the composite key on the model creation, as you outlined above.

Comment: Thanks I will try that